# I broke my “F5” key so can I re-map “F6” to be “F5?”

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, ubuntu-14.04, remapping

I broke my <kbd>F5</kbd> key. Is there any way I can re-map the <kbd>F6</kbd> button to apply the same 'refresh' function that <kbd>F5</kbd> offers?

**Update** It turns out that my <kbd>F5</kbd> wasn’t broken. I just somehow managed to get my <kbd>Function</kbd> key stuck. But—in my drunken wisdom—I pulled and pushed and twisted the <kbd>F5</kbd> key so it’s definitely broken now.

Comment: Use something autohotkey to create a new shortcut

Comment: I recommend not using alcohol as a function lubricant.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an application like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap the <kbd>F6</kbd> Key to be the <kbd>F5</kbd> Key.

Comment: Cool, could you post the config file for the re-map aswell?

Answer (score -1):

You could also use sharpkeys to remap and even disable any desired keys

Comment: Please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511)